# Flutter Bloc rebuilding only in one specific widget

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I have this widget, that consumes data from the QuestionToRepeatStepperBloc, when index in this bloc is incremented, only the text widget registers it, and displays correct value. In the Listview.Builder `if (currentQuestionIndex == questionToRepeatStepperState.currentIndex) {` is never satisfied. The information about the index being incremented is somehow not passed there.

```
class QuestionToRepeatDetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Logger log = logger(LogCategory.page, QuestionToRepeatDetailPage);

  QuestionToRepeatDetailPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScaffoldSafeAreaWidget(
      child: OriginContainerWidget(
        // todo render heading like Biologie-opravna
        heading: TranslationsConstants.repairPageHeading.tr(),
        originContainerPage: OriginContainerPage.repairPage,
        child: Container(
          // todo make this general styles
          decoration: SubcategoryDetailPageStyles.containerBoxDecoration,
          width: SubcategoryDetailPageStyles.containerWidth,
          child: BlocBuilder<QuestionToRepeatStepperBloc, QuestionToRepeatStepperState>(
            builder: (BuildContext context, QuestionToRepeatStepperState questionToRepeatStepperState) {
              int allQuestions = questionToRepeatStepperState.questionsToRepeat.length;
              int currentIndexLabel = questionToRepeatStepperState.currentIndex + 1;

              return Column(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    '$currentIndexLabel / $allQuestions',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).highlightColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: questionToRepeatStepperState.questionsToRepeat.length,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int currentQuestionIndex) {
                        // updated from BlocBuilder
                        if (currentQuestionIndex == questionToRepeatStepperState.currentIndex) {
                          log.i('STEPPER INDEX CHANGE questionToRepeatStepperState.currentIndex ${questionToRepeatStepperState.currentIndex}');

                          bool isLast = currentQuestionIndex == questionToRepeatStepperState.questionsToRepeat.length - 1;

                          return QuestionToRepeatWindowWidget(
                            questionModel: questionToRepeatStepperState.questionsToRepeat[currentQuestionIndex],
                            isLast: isLast,
                          );
                        } else {
                          // this has to be returned, if not, nothing renders on the screen, even the stuff that should render
                          // return const Offstage();
                          log.i('in else statement ${currentQuestionIndex} ${questionToRepeatStepperState.currentIndex}');
                          Text('ahojda').textColor(Colors.red);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Flutter BLOC:

```
@injectable
class QuestionToRepeatStepperBloc extends Bloc<QuestionToRepeatStepperEvent, QuestionToRepeatStepperState> {
  final Logger log = logger(LogCategory.bloc, QuestionToRepeatStepperBloc);
  QuestionToRepeatStepperBloc() : super(QuestionToRepeatStepperState.initial()) {
    on<SetupQuestions>((SetupQuestions event, Emitter<QuestionToRepeatStepperState> emit) {
      log.i("Stepper bloc receiving questions");
      emit(state.copyWith(questionsToRepeat: event.questionsToRepeat));
    });

    on<SelectOption>((SelectOption event, Emitter<QuestionToRepeatStepperState> emit) {
      log.i("Selecting or deselection option");
      List<OptionModel> currentOptionList = [...state.pickedOptionsForCurrentlyEvaluatedQuestion];

      bool optionAlreadySelected = currentOptionList.any((OptionModel option) => option.id == event.optionModel.id);

      if (optionAlreadySelected) {
        log.i('Option was already selected, removing option from selected list');
        currentOptionList.removeWhere((OptionModel option) => option.id == event.optionModel.id);
      } else {
        log.i('Option is not yet present in the selected list, adding to selected list');
        currentOptionList.add(event.optionModel);
      }
      emit(state.copyWith(pickedOptionsForCurrentlyEvaluatedQuestion: currentOptionList));
    });

    on<ShowCorrectIncorrectOptions>((ShowCorrectIncorrectOptions event, Emitter<QuestionToRepeatStepperState> emit) {
      log.i('Showing correct incorrect options');
      emit(state.copyWith(showCorrectIncorrectOptions: true));
    });

    on<ConfirmSelectionAndIncrementIndex>((ConfirmSelectionAndIncrementIndex event, Emitter<QuestionToRepeatStepperState> emit) {
      log.i('Continuing to another question to repeat');
      emit(
        state.copyWith(
          currentIndex: state.currentIndex + 1,
          showCorrectIncorrectOptions: false,
        ),
      );
      log.i('CURRENT INDEX: ${state.currentIndex}');
    });
  }
}
```

State of that BLOC:

```
part of 'question_to_repeat_stepper_bloc.dart';

enum QuestionsToRepeatAnswerState {
  initial,
  started,
  finished,
}

@unfreezed
class QuestionToRepeatStepperState extends Equatable with _$QuestionToRepeatStepperState {
  const QuestionToRepeatStepperState._();

  factory QuestionToRepeatStepperState({
    required int currentIndex,
    required List<QuestionModel> questionsToRepeat,
    required List<OptionModel> pickedOptionsForCurrentlyEvaluatedQuestion,
    required UploadStatus currentQuestionUploadStatus,
    required bool showCorrectIncorrectOptions,
    @Default(QuestionsToRepeatAnswerState.initial) QuestionsToRepeatAnswerState quizAnswerState,
  }) = _QuestionToRepeatStepperState;

  factory QuestionToRepeatStepperState.initial() => QuestionToRepeatStepperState(
        currentIndex: 0,
        questionsToRepeat: [],
        pickedOptionsForCurrentlyEvaluatedQuestion: [],
        currentQuestionUploadStatus: UploadStatus.initial,
        showCorrectIncorrectOptions: false,
        quizAnswerState: QuestionsToRepeatAnswerState.initial,
      );

  // todo potential memory leak issue
  @override
  // the old stuff
  List<Object?> get props => [currentIndex, questionsToRepeat, pickedOptionsForCurrentlyEvaluatedQuestion, currentQuestionUploadStatus, showCorrectIncorrectOptions, quizAnswerState];
}
```

Any form of help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Solved, Android Studio somehow let me running the code although I had a return statement missing in the QuestionToRepeatDetailPage in the else block